# How can I make the phplist signup form return the user to Drupal?

Tags: drupal-8, phplist

I want to embed a phplist signup form in Drupal, but strangely I couldn't find any information about it. There was a module for this, but it is no longer maintained. I tried to insert the source code of the signup page, but the data is not submitted to phplist.

EDIT: The submitting problem was solved my inserting the submit URL to the action attribute of the form tag. Anyway, after subscribing the user is forwarded to a phplist landing page, but I want them to stay on the CMS website, like this happens with the Mailchimp signup form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpList has no integration API (at least not 2 sided), so you have 2 solutions:

1. Modify phpList's index.php to redirect the user back to your CMS after subscribing. But you'll have to redo it each time a new version comes out.
2. Output your form to an iframe, so the whole subscription will take place there. Then trust the user to get back to your CMS because it will be in the background.